# CLOSE_WAIT keeping process alive on windows

Tags: windows, java, tcp

I have several java processes running on a windows server. I have noticed from time to time when I try to kill the process it remains alive. The cause seems to be sockets in CLOSE_WAIT associated with the process.

Any idea why some sockets remain in CLOSE_WAIT after I try to kill the process?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One idea- You need to tune your TCP settings, not familiar with windows at all, but generally you want to make the `TIME_WAIT` or `CLOSE_WAIT` interval shorter so connections don't hang around as long. On a busy server, sockets stacking up on you in `CLOSE_WAIT` get into the tens of thousands and consume resources needlessly... You can sniff the interface, winpcap etc,  and see if a fin is being sent, a correct (non reset) close should look like this:

```
TCP: .... 0... = (No push)
TCP: .... .0.. = (No reset)
TCP: .... ..0. = (No SYN)
TCP: .... ...1 = FIN
```

You can trace or truss the application, for instance if it uses `closesocket()`, make sure it's your getting an rc of 0, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The process is in an uninterruptible wait state due to a hardware problem, and may require a reboot. This only happens if the hardware is having the issue.

.............
Dramil Dodeja
http://dramildodeja.webnode.com/